# Regular expression to find a mention

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression in Javascript that would match, in a string like

`@Mr. Smith Hello !`

, where Mr. Smith is the name of the user, the occurrences

`Mr.` `Mr. Smith` `Mr. Smith Hello` `Mr. Smith Hello !`

For now, every regular expression that I tried returned

`@Mr. Smith Hello !` and `Mr. Smith Hello !`,

while neglecting `Mr.`, `Mr. Smith` and `Mr. Smith Hello`...

i have tried this:

`/^@(.*) /`, `/^@(.*)* /` and `/^@([^ ].*) /`

Thanks for your help !

Comment: show us your regexp's that you tried

Comment: I tried "/^@(.*) /", "/^@(.*)* /" and "/^@([^ ].*) /"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single regular expression cannot return overlapping text as separate matches, because each match consumes part of the input text.  However, you can create nested capture groups, like this (Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/bsu52a1eL9):

```
@(((([^ ]*) [^ ]*) [^ ]*) [^ ]*)
```

Of course this will only work for the exact string format you gave, having exactly 3 spaces / 4 separate words.  A better solution is to make use of the [**`substring`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [**`split`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) methods, then you can recombine the parts manually:

```
var input = "@Mr. Smith Hello !";
var parts = input.substring(1).split(' ');
//parts = ["Mr.","Smith","Hello","!"]
var temp = "";
var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
{
    if (temp != "") temp += " ";
    temp += parts[i];
    output[i] = temp;
}
//output = ["Mr.", "Mr. Smith", "Mr. Smith Hello", "Mr. Smith Hello !"]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jbk4h/